# laravel - querying with select() and with() not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm querying a model with Relationships this way:

```
$q = Repay::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
    ->with(['car:id,plate','place:id,title','offer:id,percent'])
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

It's working fine, so now I'm tyring to determine specific fields for main model. This way:

```
$q = Repay::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
    ->with(['car:id,plate','place:id,title'])
    ->select('id','paidValue')
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

But this way I'm getting all relations as "null".

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you have to select car_id and place_id in main select:

```
->select('id','paidValue', 'car_id', 'place_id')
```

So relation would know what is id of car and place.